# Capture all url segments after the initial match with Nancy

Tags: nancy

I would like to have nancy rule that matches/captures all url segments after the initial match.

For example I would like to do this:

have a url like: /views/viewname/pageid/visitid/someother

and a rule like this:

```
Get["/views/{view}/{all other values}"] = parameters =>
 {
    string view = parameters.view;

    List<string> listOfOtherValues = all other parameters..

    return ...
 };
```

listOfOtherValues would end up being:

- pageid
- visitid
- someother

I would also like to do this for querystring parameters.

given the a url like: /views/viewname?pageid=1&visitid=34&someother=hello

then listOfOtherValues would end up being:

- 1
- 34
- hello

Is this even possible with Nancy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first problem you can use regular expression as well as simple names to define your capture groups. So you just define a catch all RegEx.
For your second, you just need to enumerate through the Request.Query dictionary.

Here is some code that demonstrates both in a single route.

```
public class CustomModule : NancyModule
{
    public CustomModule() {
        Get["/views/{view}/(?<all>.*)"] = Render;
    }

    private Response Render(dynamic parameters) {
        String result = "View: " + parameters.view + "<br/>";
        foreach (var other in ((string)parameters.all).Split('/'))
            result += other + "<br/>";

        foreach (var name in Request.Query)
            result += name + ": " + Request.Query[name] + "<br/>";

        return result;
    }
}
```

With this in place you can call a URL such as `/views/home/abc/def/ghi/?x=1&y=2` and get the output
`View: home`
`abc`
`def`
`ghi`
`x: 1`
`y: 2`

Note:
The `foreach` over Request.Query is support in v0.9+

Comment: In your first example, why I can't match something like /views/home/1.2